# como usar correctamente la funcion fseek en c

Tags: c

Hola tengo una pequeña duda, como usar la funcion fseek en c para buscar un tipo de dato en especifico. He estado buscando pero ninguna respuesta me da idea de como debo usar la funcion, (estoy usando dev-c)
les dejo el codigo que tengo:

```
#include < stdio.h >
#include < string.h >

struct dClientes {
  char nombreCompleto[40];
};
struct cedula {
  int id, cuenta;
};
struct saldos {
  float saldoAnterior, saldoActual;
};
struct banco {
  cedula s;
  saldos f;
  dClientes DC;
};

int leer();
void llenaClientes(banco);
FILE *abrirArchivo();
void muestraArchivo(banco);
void muestraCuentas(banco);

int main() {
  int opc;
  banco clientes;
  do {
    printf("\nOpcion: ");
    opc = leer();
    switch (opc) {
    case 1:
      llenaClientes(clientes);
      break;
    case 2:
      muestraArchivo(clientes);
      break;
    case 3:
      muestraCuentas(clientes);
      break;
    }
  } while (opc != 0);
}

int leer() {
  int n;
  scanf("%i", &n);
  return n;
}

void muestraCuentas(banco l) {
  char cadena[sizeof(banco)], *mind;

  FILE *apufile = abrirArchivo();

  if (apufile == NULL) {
    printf("\nERROR, NO SE ENCONTRO ARCHIVO...");
  } else {
    while (!feof(apufile)) {
      /*aqui es donde quiero usar fseek para encontrar el listado de cuentas con
       * su respectivo saldo...*/
    }
    fclose(apufile);
  }
}

void muestraArchivo(banco l) {
  printf(">>>DATOS DE LOS CLIENTES<<<");

  char cadena[sizeof(banco)], *token;
  FILE *apufile = abrirArchivo();

  if (apufile == NULL) {
    printf("\nERROR, NO SE ENCONTRO ARCHIVO...");
  } else {
    while (!feof(apufile)) {
      fgets(cadena, sizeof(banco), apufile);

      if (!feof(apufile)) {
        token = NULL;

        token = strtok(cadena, "|");
        printf("\n Numero de cuenta: %s ", token);

        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
        printf("\n Cedula: %s", token);

        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
        printf("\n Saldo actual del cliente: %s", token);

        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
        printf("\n Nombre del cliente: %s", token);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(apufile);
  }
}

void llenaClientes(banco l) {
  printf("\tBienvenido al sistema de Banamex.\n\t>>>Por favor a continuacion "
         "capture sus datos<<<");

  FILE *apuB;
  fflush(stdin);

  printf("\nIngrese nombre completo del cliente: ");
  gets(l.DC.nombreCompleto);
  printf("\nIngrese el numero de cuenta: ");
  l.s.cuenta = leer();
  printf("\nIngrese el numero de cedula: ");
  l.s.id = leer();
  printf("\nIngrese el saldo del cliente: ");
  scanf("%d", &l.f.saldoActual);
  l.f.saldoAnterior = l.f.saldoActual;

  apuB = abrirArchivo();

  if (apuB == NULL) {
    printf("\nNo se pudo abrir el archivo...");
  } else {
    fprintf(apuB, "%i|%i|%f|%s|\n", l.s.id, l.s.cuenta, l.f.saldoActual,
            l.DC.nombreCompleto);
    fclose(apuB);
  }
}

FILE *abrirArchivo() {
  FILE *apufile = fopen("Banamex.txt", "a+");
  return apufile;
}
```

Comment: Hola dan-iel, bienvenido a SOes, echale un vistazo al [tour] y a [ask] para que te hagas una idea básica de como funciona el sitio, actualmente tu problema es entendible y fácil de responder. Como consejo: a veces es mejor un [mcve] a todo el código de tu programa, aisla el problema en un fragmento que represente tu problema y postealo aquí, para la proxima :P, saludos!